# ZPL code printing a layout that contains 5 different labels

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I'm trying to make a ZPL code that prints an amount of 5 different labels in a single code (I need to do in this way because in SAP I don't have any more space to add more layout), but the printer is printing only the first label and then it stops without printing the rest of the layout.

In a first attempt I made a single long layout (the white rectangle with black edge are to cover a logo of one of our client)

[image: First attempt with a single long layout]

This is the code that I got:

```
    CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~  
^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR2,2~SDTEMP_X_ETI^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ
```

I had to delete the big part that is here in the middle

```
^MMr
^PW461
^LL3998
^LS0
^FT32,800^XG0LOGO0076.GRF,1,1^FS
^FT32,1600^XG0LOGO0076.GRF,1,1^FS
^FT32,2400^XG0LOGO0076.GRF,1,1^FS
^FT32,3200^XG0LOGO0076.GRF,1,1^FS
^FT32,3968^XG0LOGO0076.GRF,1,1^FS
^FT95,335^A0B,42,40^FH\^FDDescription:^FS
^FT95,1136^A0B,42,40^FH\^FDDescription:^FS
^FT99,1938^A0B,42,40^FH\^FDDescription:^FS
^FT99,2734^A0B,42,40^FH\^FDDescription:^FS
^FT99,3521^A0B,42,40^FH\^FDDescription:^FS
^BY6,3,87^FT462,719^BCB,,Y,Y
^FD>:T00040^FS
^BY6,3,87^FT462,1520^BCB,,Y,Y
^FD>:T00041^FS
^BY6,3,87^FT465,2323^BCB,,Y,Y
^FD>:T00042^FS
^FT268,373^A0B,54,52^FH\^FD-1 of^FS
^FT268,1175^A0B,54,52^FH\^FD-1 of^FS
^FT272,1977^A0B,54,52^FH\^FD-1 of^FS
^FT272,781^A0B,54,52^FH\^FDT00083^FS
^FT272,2773^A0B,54,52^FH\^FD-1 of^FS
^FT272,1583^A0B,54,52^FH\^FDT00083^FS
^FT272,3560^A0B,54,52^FH\^FD-1 of^FS
^FT270,220^A0B,54,52^FH\^FDT00039^FS
^FT276,2385^A0B,54,52^FH\^FDT00083^FS
^FT270,1022^A0B,54,52^FH\^FDT00039^FS
^BY6,3,87^FT465,3119^BCB,,Y,Y
^FD>:T00043^FS
^FT274,1824^A0B,54,52^FH\^FDT00039^FS
^FT276,3181^A0B,54,52^FH\^FDT00083^FS
^FT274,2620^A0B,54,52^FH\^FDT00039^FS
^FT276,3967^A0B,54,52^FH\^FDT00083^FS
^FT274,3406^A0B,54,52^FH\^FDT00039^FS
^BY6,3,87^FT465,3905^BCB,,Y,Y
^FD>:T00044^FS
^PQT00093,0,1,Y^XZ
^XA^ID0LOGO0076.GRF^FS^XZ
^XA^ID0LOGO0076.GRF^FS^XZ
^XA^ID0LOGO0076.GRF^FS^XZ
^XA^ID0LOGO0076.GRF^FS^XZ
^XA^ID0LOGO0076.GRF^FS^XZ
```

I wasn't able to figure out what to do, so I made a second layout that from the Zebra Designer program shows graphically 5 different labels (same as before for the rectangles):

[image: Second attempt with a layout with 5 lables]

And this is the code that I got:

```
CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR2,2~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ
```

I had to delete the big part that is here in the middle

```
^MMT
^PW449
^LL3998
^LS0
^FT32,800^XG0LOGO0076.GRF,1,1^FS
^FT32,1600^XG0LOGO0076.GRF,1,1^FS
^FT32,2400^XG0LOGO0076.GRF,1,1^FS
^FT32,3200^XG0LOGO0076.GRF,1,1^FS
^FT32,3968^XG0LOGO0076.GRF,1,1^FS
^FT91,324^A0B,42,40^FH\^FDDescription:^FS
^FT260,3547^A0B,54,52^FH\^FD-1 of^FS
^FT91,1126^A0B,42,40^FH\^FDDescription:^FS
^FT259,2761^A0B,54,52^FH\^FD-1 of^FS
^FT95,1928^A0B,42,40^FH\^FDDescription:^FS
^FT258,1965^A0B,54,52^FH\^FD-1 of^FS
^FT95,2724^A0B,42,40^FH\^FDDescription:^FS
^BY6,3,87^FT444,709^BCB,,Y,Y
^FD>:T00040^FS
^FT258,1163^A0B,54,52^FH\^FD-1 of^FS
^BY6,3,87^FT444,1510^BCB,,Y,Y
^FD>:T00041^FS
^BY6,3,87^FT444,2312^BCB,,Y,Y
^FD>:T00042^FS
^FT258,362^A0B,54,52^FH\^FD-1 of^FS
^FT95,3510^A0B,42,40^FH\^FDDescription:^FS
^FT258,3955^A0B,50,50^FH\^FDT00083^FS
^FT257,3169^A0B,50,50^FH\^FDT00083^FS
^BY6,3,87^FT444,3109^BCB,,Y,Y
^FD>:T00043^FS
^FT256,2373^A0B,50,50^FH\^FDT00083^FS
^FT256,1571^A0B,50,50^FH\^FDT00083^FS
^FT256,770^A0B,50,50^FH\^FDT00083^FS
^FT260,3394^A0B,54,50^FH\^FDT00039^FS
^FT259,2608^A0B,54,50^FH\^FDT00039^FS
^FT258,1812^A0B,54,50^FH\^FDT00039^FS
^FT258,1010^A0B,54,50^FH\^FDT00039^FS
^FT258,208^A0B,54,50^FH\^FDT00039^FS
^BY6,3,87^FT444,3895^BCB,,Y,Y
^FD>:T00044^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ
^XA^ID0LOGO0076.GRF^FS^XZ
^XA^ID0LOGO0076.GRF^FS^XZ
^XA^ID0LOGO0076.GRF^FS^XZ
^XA^ID0LOGO0076.GRF^FS^XZ
^XA^ID0LOGO0076.GRF^FS^XZ
```

I think that is a problem with the laser sensor maybe, because it can see the space between one label and another so it stops the printing, am I right?
So what do I need to change in my ZPL or printer settings to print one of the two layout?
It's two days that I'm struggling to understand what I have to do.

PS.: we are using these type of labels:

[image: The labels that I'm using]

I thank everybody who will answer my question in advance,
bye

Comment: What entity are you printing against? (Item, Order line, etc..) What does SAP usually print? What fields do you want on the label? Are the 5 labels the same printed 5x, or is there something different about the labels?

Comment: I'm printing against an order line, SAP usually prints datas labels and packaging labels.
These labels are additional labels for spare parts.
On the labels I need some logos, the descriprion of the spare parts and the amount of the kit (the maximum amount is 5).
I need SAP to print every time the 5 labels, but only to compile the labels when I need them.

Comment: I'm still having difficulty understanding what you are trying to get printed. I would suggest starting with a far more basic label to build from there. Do you want all the 5 labels to be identical? Are you trying to print serial or sequential data generated by the ZPL?